# Haskell- Pattern syntax in expression context: _

Tags: syntax, haskell

I have been learning some Haskell and writing very simple programs. I want to make a function that will return the element at the given position. Here's what I tried to do-

```
elempos::Int->[a]->a
elempos n (b:_)=head (drop n (b:_) )
```

But I'm getting this error when I load the Test.hs file in the GHCi editor.

```
Pattern syntax in expression context: _
```

And it says Failed, modules loaded:none.
Since I'm very new to the language I don't really have a proper idea what the mistake is(currently at chapter 4 of learn you a haskell). Can anyone tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: `_` as pattern means "I don't care what it is", so it is not only not allowed, but makes no sense to "feed" it to a function like `drop` (which *needs* to know its arguments).

Comment: There is !! operator doing what you need.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`_` is valid only inside patterns, you're trying to use it inside an expression: `head (drop n (b : _))`. Since you don't really need to decompose the list, and you do need the tail, the solution is to do:

```
elempos n xs = head (drop n xs)
```

Comment: Ah.. Thank you for clarifying. I might have got too excited to use the _ in a function in any way possible after I saw it. =) Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Andariel: don't forget to accept his answer if it solved your problem, please :)